# C sqrt not working properly on floating point numbers below 1 but above 0

Tags: c, sqrt, math.h

I am trying to create a vector with random dimensions, but with a magnitude of 1. This is what I've come up with (removed the rand() function and replaced it with a number common to both pieces of code.):

```
  float x = sqrt((4566%100)/100.f);
  float y = sqrt(1.f-x);
  
  printf("%f, %f\n", x, y);
  printf("%f\n", (x*x)+(y*y));
```

The output is this:

```
0.812404, 0.433124
0.847596
```

but when I remove the inverse of the pythagorean theorum (with the code looking a little something like this):

```
  float x = (4566%100)/100.f;
  float y = 1.f-x;
  printf("%f, %f\n", x, y);
  printf("%f\n", x+y);
```

the output looks like this:

```
0.660000, 0.340000
1.000000
```

Based on the assumption that I'm not insane, the output of the last line of the first piece of code should be 1, and the vector being printed above should be something completely different. I can only assume that the thing that has gone wrong is in the `sqrt` function. If it is, could someone help me fix it and if it isn't, could someone help me identify my error?

Comment: In the first snippet `x + y*y` should be giving 1, and not `x*x+y*y`

Comment: Side note: Since you're working with floats instead of doubles, prefer `sqrtf()` over `sqrt()` (And similar for any other math functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, according to the Pythagorean theorem, `sqrt(x * x + y * y) = 1`, then `y` is not equal to `sqrt(1.f-x)`. It should be `sqrt(1.f-x*x)`:

- `sqrt(x * x + y * y) = 1`
- (square both sides) => `x * x + y * y = 1`
- (subtract `x * x` from both sides) => `y * y = 1 - x * x`
- (calculate the square root of both sides) => `y = sqrt(1 - x * x)`

Answer (score 1):

Given the computation for `x`, this computation of `y` is incorrect:

> ```
>   float y = sqrt(1.f-x);
> ```

You need to subtract the *square* of `x`:

```
  float y = sqrt(1.f-x*x);
```

Since `x` is between 0 and 1, x<sup>2</sup> < x, and that will yield a larger (and correct, modulo FP error) value of `y`.